# TextPad 7 does not auto reload

Tags: textpad

TextPad 7 does not auto reload.  Does anyone knows how to turn it on.

I have done what I had in the past: set the Auto-Reload flag of "When files are modified by another process:" group, from the menu: Configure.Preferences.  However, in TextPad 7 the files do not Auto-Reloaded.

Many thanks,
Avi

Comment: Works just fine for me.  I have selected `Auto-reload`, Ignore differences in modification times less than 2 seconds `off` and Check for file size changes `on`.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure Textpad to reload the file without prompting.

Go to Configure->Preferences...->File, then select the Auto-Reload option under When files are modified by another process.

One point to note, if the cursor is at the end of the file, TextPad will keep it at the end as updates are made so the file will scroll nicely. If the cursor is elsewhere in the file, it won't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some preference changes. You can configure to reload on F5 using link

http://skatterbrainz.blogspot.in/2010/11/textpad-tip-assign-f5-to-refresh-view.html

Basically under preference -> keyboard -> all command - > select FileRevert -> assign F5.

And all good